# Computing a contour integral over curve not centered at origin

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Consider the integral

$$
\int_C \frac{1}{z} \, dz
$$

where $C$ is the circle of radius $R$ centered at the point $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$. We parametrize the curve by $z(\theta) = z_0 + Re^{i\theta}$ where $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. It follows immediately that $dz = iRe^{i\theta} \, d\theta$. Substituting, we obtain

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{z_0 + Re^{i\theta}} \cdot iRe^{i\theta} \, d\theta = iR \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i\theta}}{z_0 + Re^{i\theta}} \, d\theta.
$$

Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed in commuting the integral? I suppose this is more of a calculus question than a complex analysis question. I apologize if this is very elementary; my integration is a little rusty.

Comment: This depends on what $R$ is, if the circle manages to encircle the origin, the answer is $2\pi i$ (argument principle). If not, it's $0$ (Morera's theorem).

Comment: Are you asking for a complex analysis proof, or a differential calculus proof?

Comment: Write in terms of real and imaginary parts separately, and integrate that.

Comment: And its not defined if the circle passes through zero.

Comment: Since the integrand is a rational function of of trigonometric functions, the mighty Tangent-Half-Angle Substitution is guaranteed to work. (Though most people would probably say you shouldn't use a boulder when a pebble will do...)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

> $$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f'(\theta)}{f(\theta)} \, d\theta = \ln(f(\theta))\Big|_{\theta = a}^{\theta=b}  .$$